# how can a telegram bot send an aligned table? I tried sending a table image but it clogs up the user's memory?

Tags: telebot

I'm making a telegram bot shop and there is a problem related with a basket. I want my telebot to send an aligned table but i got this

This is what my bot sends

[image: 1]

This is a pandas table converted to Markdown. How can i fix my bot ?

Answer (score 0):

Telegram doesn't have the ability to render tables inside messages. The best thing you can do is use ```` ``` ```` quotes to make font monospaced. In that case, you can write your table using tabulation